# Remove page break before glossary

Tags: glossaries

I have a problem with `glossaries` package.

When I insert my glossary with `\printglossary[title=Glossaire]` it is inserted in page IV. But my glossary start on page V ; the `printglossary` make a page break before adding my glossary and I don't want that.

I try to use `\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage` before `\printglossary` and that doesn't work, I had again a page break.

I also try to give `onepage` or `oneside` options to my `\documentclass` and that doesn't work too.

How can I do to remove the page break before my glossary ?

--

Here is pages IV and V. And my Table of Contents.

[image: pages IV and V]
[image: Table of Content]

Comment: Try with `\clearpage\begingroup\let\newpage\relax\printglossary[title=Glossaire]\endgroup`. This first inserts a regular `\clearpage` to get you on the correct page, after which it nullifies `\newpage`. `\cleardoublepage` calls `\clearpage` which, in tern, uses `\newpage`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Try `\renewcommand{\glsclearpage}{\clearpage}` or `\renewcommand{\glsclearpage}{}`

Comment: Thanks @NicolaTalbot \renewcommand{\glsclearpage}{} works !

Comment: @Werner you are a life-saver man. :) Thanks very much

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `glossaries` package provides the user command `\glsclearpage` which is used internally to implement the page break before the glossary. The default behaviour is as follows:

If the package option `section=chapter` has been used (default when used with classes that define `\chapter`), then `\glsclearpage` does `\clearpage` if `\cleardoublepage` hasn't been defined. If `\cleardoublepage` has been defined, then it checks the `openright` setting and does `\cleardoublepage` if true, otherwise it does `\clearpage`. If `\if@openright` isn't defined but `\cleardoublepage` is defined it does `\cleardoublepage`. (Of the top of my head, I can't remember the reason for this last case, but I vaguely remember there was a class that caused this decision. I think most classes that define `\cleardoublepage` also define `\if@openright`.)

If the package option `section` has been set to something other than `chapter`, then `\glsclearpage` does nothing as no page break is usually required in this instance.

If you want to change the default settings you can redefine `\glsclearpage` as required. For example, if you want to use `\clearpage` instead of `\cleardoublepage` you can do:

```
\renewcommand*{\glsclearpage}{\clearpage}
```

or if you want to completely suppress the page break (regardless of the `section` setting):

```
\renewcommand*{\glsclearpage}{}
```

Comment: I wonder why @Werne's [approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198231/remove-page-break-before-glossary#comment459881_198231) works for me, while yours doesn't. Following your approach of using `\renewcommand*{\glsclearpage}{}`, I still have the glossary title on a new page, and the glossary table itself is moved to the next page.