# Can't get rid of blank page

Tags: glossaries, blank-page

I'm writing my dissertation in overleaf but I've got a blank page between my aknowledgements and my glossary. I've tried using oneside and openany but it still stays. Below is the part of the main.tex file that contains the relevant code

```
% book - Default class for a normal book
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,table]{book}

\usepackage{packages}
% Almost all the settings are defined in packages.sty
% Put a grey textual watermark on document pages (PDF mode)
%\usepackage{draftwatermark}
% If you want to change the default DRAFT text
%\SetWatermarkText{DRAFT}
% If you want to change the default grey color of the text
%\SetWatermarkColor{red}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%   DOCUMENT: an ordered list of files    %
%             that you can include or not %
%             in your document            %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

% Title Page %
\include{frontmatter/titlepage}

%% FRONTMATTER %%
\frontmatter

% ABSTRACT %
\include{frontmatter/abstract}

% ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS %
\include{frontmatter/acknowledgments}

% GLOSSARY %
\include{frontmatter/glossary}

% CONTENTS
\include{frontmatter/contents}

%% MAINMATTER %%
% The pages inside of mainmatter are in Arabic numerals and the chapters will have numeration
\mainmatter

%\part{If you want parts}
\include{1_Introduction/intro}
\include{2_Background/background}
\include{3_LiteratureReview/litreview}
%\include{chapter4/ch4}
% \include{chapter5/ch5}
% \include{chapter6/ch6}

%% APPENDICES %%
\appendix
\include{appendix/appendix1}
%\include{appendix2/appendix2}

%% BACKMATTER %%
% The pages inside of backmatter are in Arabic numerals and the chapters will not have numeration
\backmatter

% BIBLIOGRAPHY WITH BIBTEX %
\include{backmatter/bibliography}
")

% INDEX %
\include{backmatter/index }
\end{document
```

EDIT: Below are my aknowledgementand glossary sections:

```
% ========================= Acknowledgments ==============================
\providecommand\phantomsection{} \phantomsection
\thispagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}\small\normalsize
\begin{center}
\textbf{ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}\\[3\baselineskip]
\end{center}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.66} \small\normalsize%
I acknowledge the people who helped me.
```

```
\newglossarystyle{modsuper}{%
\setglossarystyle{super}%
\renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\tablehead{}\tabletail{}%
     \begin{supertabular}{@{}lp{\glsdescwidth}}}%<----no margin
    {\end{supertabular}}%
\renewcommand{\glsgroupskip}{}%
\renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##2} & ##3\glspostdescription\space ##5\\[2pt]}%
}

\glsaddall
\printglossary[type=main,style=modsuper,nonumberlist]
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

Comment: there is not enough in your example to see why you should get a blank page.  Please provide an example that shows the problem.

Comment: I've uploaded the snippets of my aknowledgement and glossary sections - not sure what else I need to upload since I'm new to latex, sorry

Comment: you need to edit the main document part so that we can run it and see a blank page and debug for you. currently your first block is missing `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` and includes files we don't have

Comment: I’ve uploaded the main tex file with the \begin - I had tk upload it from mobile so sorry if there are any mistakes

Comment: try to do as you are asking us to do, copy those three code blocks that you have posted and try to run them to see the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find an answer here: [Remove page break before glossary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198231/remove-page-break-before-glossary/) which gave me the line of code:

`\clearpage\begingroup\let\newpage\relax\printglossary[title=Glossary]\endgroup`

which, when put at the top of my glossary file, solves the issue